# How to disable RepositoryRestHandlerMapping and EndpointHandlerMapping?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-hateoas

I am currently building an application with a REST interface, using Spring Boot, Hibernate and Spring-HATEOAS. My data model is defined as beans with `@Entity` annotation and I am using Spring's feature to automatically set up a Hibernate repository (Creating an interface extending `PagingAndSortingRepository`). My application is completely annotation-driven, i.e., I have no `web.xml` but configure everything with the Spring annotations like `@Configuration`, `@Bean` etc., and start the application from my `main` method with the help of `SpringApplication.run(MyApp.class, args);`

This works fine, but with this approach, a `RepositoryRestHandlerMapping` and `EndpointHandlerMapping` is created. These create a bunch of resources I neither need nor want. I implement my own controllers because they need to do more than the standard logic.

How can I prevent this default behaviour and disable these mappings?

Comment: `RepositoryRestHandlerMapping` is provided by Spring Data REST. If you don't want it then don't include it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I need the other REST functions, like `@RestController` annotation. But I found a feasible solution myself now:

`RepositoryRestHandlerMapping` should not be disabled, but it is possible to disable exporting of repositories by annotating them with `@RepositoryRestResource(exported = false)`. I did this with all my repositories and now, the wildcard resources are still installed, but no repositories are registered to resolve against them, making them effectively disappear. Trying to access such a resource gives a `404` as expected.

Same for `EndpointHandlerMapping`, which comes from `spring-boot-actuator` and installs some endpoints like `/info`, `/metrics` etc. This is handy and should be present in a REST application; when I register my application with an Eureka server, it automatically generates links to some of these. To use this correctly, the endpoints can for example be configured via `@Bean`, like this:

```
@Configuration
public class InfoConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public InfoEndpoint infoEndpoint {
        Map<String, Object> info = ...
        return new InfoEndpoint(info);
    }
}
```

The `info` above is constant info, if there were info which is subject to change, one could override `InfoEndpoint` and supply a custom implementation of `getAdditionalInfo()`.

Answer (score 27):

Exclude RepositoryRestMvcAutoConfiguration in your main class.

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = RepositoryRestMvcAutoConfiguration.class)
```

Comment: It also works in this way:
`@SpringBootApplication(exclude = RepositoryRestMvcAutoConfiguration.class)`

Answer (score 4):

### **Kotlin**

- **Exclude Specific resource:** To exclude only a specific Repository use the code below in the specific interface, the mapping in the Controller will still work.

  ```
  @Repository
  @RestResource(exported = false)
  interface SongRepository : JpaRepository<Song, Int>
  ```
- **Entirely:** To exclude entirely, use the Kotlin version of the previous answers in the main class:

  ```
   @SpringBootApplication
   @EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = arrayOf(RepositoryRestMvcAutoConfiguration::class))
   class WebserviceApplication
  ```

Answer (score 1):

use below dependency

```
 <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
```

instead of

```
   <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

The auto creation of HAL resources also comes out of the box when added below dependency.

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-rest-hal-explorer</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

As the dependency name says, it creates HAL explorer links for you, automatically.
Delete this dependency if you don't want auto creation of controllers.